# Ошибка при создании таймера обратного отсчета в python

Tags: python, tkinter

Пытаюсь создать таймер обратного отсчета на 3 минуты с помощью Python Tkinter. По истечении 3 минут окно должно закрыться. Возникает ошибка и я не могу понять почему. При запуске окна ничего кроме синей полоски на зеленом фоне нет.

Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime
from time import strptime, time
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

root = Tk()

root.title('QuizopTimer')

root.geometry('1000x800')

root['bg'] = 'limegreen'

def update_time():
    format = '%H:%M:%S'
    s2 = (datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=3)).strftime(format)
    now = (datetime.now()).strftime(format)
    s3 = datetime.strptime(s2, format) - datetime.strptime(now, format)
    timerlbl.config(text=s3)
    if not s3 == '00:00:00':
        now2 = (datetime.now()).strftime(format)
        s4 = datetime.strptime(s2, format) - datetime.strptime(now2, format)
        timerlbl.config(text=s4)
    else:
        root.destroy()
    timerlbl.after(1000, update_time)


timerlbl = Label(root, font=('calibri', 50, 'bold'), background='blue', foreground='white')

timerlbl.pack(anchor=CENTER)
root.mainloop()

update_time()
```

Ошибка:

```
Возникло исключение: TclError
invalid command name ".!label"
  File "C:\Games\quizopfortrn\timertest.py", line 18, in update_time
    timerlbl.config(text=s3)
  File "C:\Games\quizopfortrn\timertest.py", line 31, in <module>
    update_time()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый вызов `update_time` должен быть до вызова `root.mainloop()`, т.к. всё что следует за ним будет выполнено только при завершении программы.

Второй момент, это замер прошедшего времени - он у вас при каждом вызове `update_time` равен 3 минутам, потому что вычисляется внутри функции: вычисление *финиша* надо сделать один раз перед первым запуском таймера.

```py
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta

root = Tk()
root.title('QuizopTimer')
root.geometry('300x200')
root['bg'] = 'limegreen'


def update_time():
    now = datetime.now()
    if now < target:
        remains = round((target - now).total_seconds())
        text = time(second=remains % 60, minute=remains // 60).strftime(format)
        timerlbl.config(text=text)
    else:
        root.destroy()
    timerlbl.after(1000, update_time)


timerlbl = Label(root, font=('calibri', 50, 'bold'), background='blue', foreground='white')
timerlbl.pack(anchor=CENTER)

format = '%H:%M:%S'
target = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=3)

update_time()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Благодарю за указание ошибки, но при запуске кода выходит другая ошибка: ValueError
second must be in 0..59

Comment: да, это я упростил для тестирования, сейчас подправлю.

Comment: я попытался встроить его в свою программу но выходит ошибка RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in __instancecheck__. я встроил его так - если произошло нажатие на кнопку то вызывается функция которая останавливает функцию таймера и переход на следующий вопрос - если время закончилось то вызывается функция перехода на следующий вопрос. Когда запускаю код если кнопка не нажата, то таймер идет по кругу без перехода на следующий вопрос а просто начинается заново.